# Database Select returns empty results

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

So I'm trying to show the results of a simple query in a joomla component,

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'SELECT r.number, r.date, q.id_category'.
         'FROM #__question AS q, #__reponse AS r'.
         'WHERE q.name = r.name'.
         'GROUP BY r.number';

$db->setQuery($query);                           
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
if(!$result)
    echo "no results found!";
else 
    echo "results found";
```

What I get is always "no results found!", usually the same method works just fine.. but now it doesn't!

the tables are not empty, and the query is correct I tested it directly in the DB.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($result);` just to see what is being returned, if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solving these problems is printing out the query.  Your query is constructed as:

```
     'SELECT r.number, r.date, q.id_category'.
     'FROM #__question AS q, #__reponse AS r'.
     'WHERE q.name = r.name'.
     'GROUP BY r.number;
```

The query will start:  'SELECT r.number, r.date, q.id_categoryFROM . . .'.  In other words, it is rife with syntax errors.  Try adding spaces judiciously as in:

```
     'SELECT r.number, r.date, q.id_category '.
     'FROM #__question AS q, #__reponse AS r '.
     'WHERE q.name = r.name '.
     'GROUP BY r.number;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement where it fails, add this line: `$db->getErrorMsg();`.  This will show you  the error message that is returned for your query and can help you troubleshoot.